# create a trigger that will update the attribute on a table when rows are inserted, deleted, or updated

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables

- Line (inv_number line_num p_code line_units line_price)
- product (P_code P_desit _P_indate P_qoh P_min P_price p_dicount v_code P_min_order P_Reorder

I have to create a trigger that will automatically update the attribute p_qoh in the product table for a given product.

So, everytime i INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE a row from the line table, it will with reduce, update, or increase the P_QOH attribute.

this is all i have so far

```
create or replace trigger TRG_LINE_PRODUCT
after insert update or delete on TBL_CH08_PRODUCT
for each row
begin
```

Comment: Not sure what your question is, but the manual has plenty of examples that you can study.

Answer (score 1):

You must first understand where to create the trigger, in this case the target table is PRODUCT, but the logical condition of your software tell us that the source table of the event is LINE.

The triggers look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Trigger TRG_LINE_PRODUCT
  After Insert Or Update Or Delete On LINE
  Referencing Old As Old New As New
  For Each Row
Declare
Begin
  If inserting Then
    If :New.p_code Is Not Null Then
      Update PRODUCT
      Set    p_qoh = p_qoh + 1
      Where  p_code = :New.p_code;
    End If;
  ElsIf updating Then
    If Nvl(:Old.p_code, 'XyZ@') <> Nvl(:New.p_code, 'XyZ@') Then
      Update PRODUCT
      Set    p_qoh = p_qoh - 1
      Where  p_code = :Old.p_code;    
      Update PRODUCT
      Set    p_qoh = p_qoh + 1
      Where  p_code = :New.p_code;    
    End If;
  ElsIf deleting Then
    If :Old.p_code Is Not Null Then
      Update PRODUCT
      Set    p_qoh = p_qoh - 1
      Where  p_code = :Old.p_code;    
    End If;
  End If;
Exception
  When Others Then
    Null;
End TRG_LINE_PRODUCT;
```

The trigger to know which event "trigger", have the keywords inserting, updating and deleting respectively.

for the case of updating, one form to know if the columns target changes if comparing the :new and :old data with this keywords.